# Codeigniter 3 SQL Injection query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-injection, codeigniter-3

Supose that `$this->input->post('location')` holds an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
)
```

Is this query "Sql Injection" safe?

```
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($this->input->post('location')) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT id 
        FROM location
        WHERE id IN ($in)";
$locations = $this->db->query($sql, $this->input->post('location'));
```

Thanks!

Comment: yes, this is pretty safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ase seen on http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html
Yes it is safe to do like that. But You need only one '?'.

So the code should be like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id 
        FROM location
        WHERE id IN (?)";
$locations = $this->db->query($sql, $this->input->post('location'));
```

Comment: Thks a lot Dimitrios Desyllas!

Answer (score 3):

i'm unsure if this is worth an answer, but i'm doing it anyway,
yes your query is safe like alex said in the comments but what i don't understand is the unnecessary complexity with str_repeat - i'm not sure but there are alternatives in CI to write down a query like that:

```
$query = $this->db
            ->select("id")
            ->from("location")
            ->where_in("id",$this->input->post("location"))
            ->get();
```

The query above, does the job too. Am i overlooking something here or are you just unaware about the built in query builder ?

Comment: Thks a lot sintakonte! I was unaware of this nicer solution. Thks again :)